# Ocaml struct like we do in C

Tags: struct, types, module, ocaml

I want to write a recursive struct, like we do in C, but in Ocaml.
I want we contains a boolean and a list of recursive copies of elements of the same type.
How can I do that in Ocaml?

Answer (score 0):

OCaml type declarations are recursive by default. So there's nothing special to do to get something like you describe. If you literally want a list inside your struct, you can define something like this:

```
type mystruct = { b: bool; others: mystruct list }
```

If you want a "linked list" of structures of your given type, you could define something more like this:

```
type mystruct2 = { b: bool; rest : mystruct2 option }
```

One key here is that the `rest` element is an option type so that your list can end at some point.

There are many other ways to define this basic structure. A more idiomatic OCaml definition might be to use a variant type:

```
type mylist = Last | Node of bool * mylist
```

This last type isn't exactly equivalent because a value of your described type always contains at least one boolean, and this type has a value (`Last`) with no booleans. In practice this usually turns out to be what you want.

**Update**

Here are two top-level variables of each of these types. In each pair the first is as small as possible and the second is a little larger.

```
let v10 = { b = true; others = []}
let v11 = { b  = false; others = [ {b = true; others = []} ] }

let v20 = { b = true; rest = None }
let v21 = { b = false; rest = Some { b = true; rest = None } }

let v30 = Last
let v31 = Node (true, Last)
```

If you have basic questions like this, it might be worthwhile to work through an OCaml tutorial, maybe one of those listed here: https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/

Comment: Thanks!
But now, how do I create a new variable of type mystruct?

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff, but I will update my answer.